# 'Decimal' and 'Numeric' is not available in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, decimal, numeric, pgadmin

I want to create a new column in my table with a type decimal and numeric, but it is not available in my `Data Type` option. Why is it?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure which tool you are using to create columns bubt decimal and numeric types are supported in postgresql http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: @SunilBN - Yeah, Ive been through that page. Im using Pgadmin 1.14.2

Comment: The types decimal and numeric are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard. Decimal doesn't appear in the list but Numeric does. Please show the data types starting with N.

Comment: @Elad --> Thanks. That's the right answer. You may put your answer to the answer section so that I can mark it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types decimal and numeric are equivalent. Both types are part of the SQL standard. Decimal doesn't appear in the list but Numeric does.

[image]